# How to save variable in for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, random, var

I have made a random password generator.In function `void passwordGenerator(int sizeOfPassword)`
The problem here is this I am trying to save the password generated by the program in `sum` but I don't know how to do it properly.

How do I save random digits password in `sum`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void passwordGenerator(int sizeOfPassword)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    char allChars[] = {"0123456789!@#$%^&*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    char sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfPassword; i++){
        sum = sum + allChars[rand()%sizeOfPassword];
    }
    std::cout<<sum<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int sizeOutput;
    char wannaPlay = 'y';
    while(wannaPlay == 'y'){
        std::cout<<"Enter the size of password: ";
        std::cin>>sizeOutput;
        passwordGenerator(sizeOutput);
        std::cout<<"\nRun Again[y/n]? : ";
        std::cin>>wannaPlay;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Thank you**

Comment: It seems like you want to save a sequence of characters instead of a single one. Try using a `std::string` with `+=` to add each character.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes I am trying to get sequence of array

Comment: `sum` is a single character, change it to `std::string`, if you want an array you can use `sum.data()`  after you've finished building the string

Comment: @AlanBirtles ```std::string sum = sum + allChars[rand()%sizeOfPassword];``` like this ?

Comment: No, change your declaration of `sum` to `std::string`

Comment: ok @AlanBirtles

Comment: @AlanBirtles OMG thanks it is solved

Comment: Other errors. `srand(time(NULL));` should be at the start of `main`. and `allChars[rand()%sizeOfPassword]` should be `allChars[rand()%sizeof allChars]`

Comment: @john Thanks I will add ```srand(time(NULL)); ``` in ```main()``` but for second one you are wrong ```sizeOfPassword``` is a parameter in function ```passwordGenerator```.

Comment: If you want your password to possibly contain any of the characters from the array then John is correct

Comment: @John sorry I was not paying attention to what u was saying yes you are correct

Comment: I think you need to take a step back here and do some study of variables. You said you needed a string, yet you had defined the variable as a char (not an array) so single letter. This is basic core variable principles. So if you ground yourself with this understanding some of these issues can be avoided.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I will definitely look into it but it's not about knowledge gaps it's about practice and experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might display letter by letter:

```
void passwordGenerator(int sizeOfPassword)
{
    const char allChars[] = {"0123456789!@#$%^&*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfPassword; i++){
        std::cout << allChars[rand() % sizeof (allChars)];
    }
}
```

or building a string:

```
std::string passwordGenerator(int sizeOfPassword)
{
    const char allChars[] = {"0123456789!@#$%^&*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    std::string password;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfPassword; i++){
        password += allChars[rand() % sizeof (allChars)];
    }
    return password;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud earlier I used first code u have mentioned but I needed to store the output in variable so thank you again